# GridCommandEventArgs items have no data values

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with which I need to add, update, and delete data. I've gotten the functionality to work, but I also need to do some checking on the data before it gets added/updated, including setting a field based on other data. I also want to log what was done.

My Insert functionality is working. The RadGrid is as follows:

```
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="CarrierRadGrid" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="False" Width="100%" Height="800px" PageSize="20" da
                AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="CarrierData" ShowStatusBar="True"
                OnInsertCommand="CarrierRadGrid_InsertCommand" OnItemInserted="CarrierRadGrid_ItemInserted" AllowAutomaticInserts="true"
                OnUpdateCommand="CarrierRadGrid_UpdateCommand" OnItemUpdated="CarrierRadGrid_ItemUpdated" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
                OnDeleteCommand="CarrierRadGrid_DeleteCommand" OnItemDeleted="CarrierRadGrid_ItemDeleted" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
                Skin="Telerik" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditColumn="false" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="false">
                <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="false">
                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" SaveScrollPosition="true" FrozenColumnsCount="5" />
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                    <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" AllowResizeToFit="true" />
                    <ClientEvents OnRowDeleting="void 0" />
                </ClientSettings>
                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
                <ExportSettings HideStructureColumns="true">
                </ExportSettings>
                <HeaderContextMenu EnableAutoScroll="False">
                </HeaderContextMenu>
                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="CarrierScacID" DataSourceID="CarrierData" AllowAutomaticInserts="true" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
                    CommandItemDisplay="Top" HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand" EditMode="InPlace">
                    <CommandItemSettings
                        ShowExportToWordButton="false"
                        ShowExportToCsvButton="false"
                        ShowExportToPdfButton="false"
                        ShowAddNewRecordButton="true">
                    </CommandItemSettings>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Edit" InsertText="Add"
                            UpdateText="Update" HeaderStyle-Width="30px" UniqueName="CarrierEditButton" />
                        <telerik:GridClientDeleteColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" Text="Delete" HeaderStyle-Width="30px" UniqueName="CarrierDeleteButton"
                            ConfirmTextFields="CarrierScac" ConfirmTextFormatString="Are you sure you want to delete carrier {0}?" CommandName="Delete" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CarrierScacID" HeaderText="CarrierScacID" UniqueName="CarrierScacID" ReadOnly="True" Display="false" />
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadLabel runat="server" ID="CarrierScac" Text='<% #Bind("CarrierScac") %>' ViewStateMode="Disabled" Enabled="false" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="CarrierScac" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("CarrierScac") %>' />
                            </InsertItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadLabel runat="server" ID="CarrierScac" Text='<% #Bind("CarrierScac") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CarrierScac" HeaderText="SCAC" UniqueName="CarrierScac" FilterControlWidth="40px" HeaderStyle-Width="75px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CarrierName" HeaderText="Carrier Name" UniqueName="CarrierName" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
                            HeaderStyle-Width="200px" FilterControlWidth="160px" FilterControlAltText="Filter by Carrier Name" SortExpression="CarrierName" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" UniqueName="Address" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
                            HeaderStyle-Width="200px" FilterControlWidth="160px" FilterControlAltText="Filter by Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="City" HeaderText="City" UniqueName="City" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="State" HeaderText="State" UniqueName="State" FilterControlWidth="30px" HeaderStyle-Width="65px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ZIP" HeaderText="ZIP" UniqueName="ZIP" FilterControlWidth="55px" HeaderStyle-Width="90px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" UniqueName="Country" FilterControlWidth="55px" HeaderStyle-Width="90px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact" UniqueName="Contact" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="110px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" UniqueName="Phone" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="115px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" UniqueName="Fax" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="115px" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="User" HeaderText="User" UniqueName="User" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Update" HeaderText="Update" UniqueName="Update" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="230px" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" UniqueName="Comments" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="230px" ReadOnly="true" />
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

In code-behind, I have the following:

```
    Protected Sub CarrierRadGrid_InsertCommand(sender As Object, e As GridCommandEventArgs)
        e = SetCommentsField(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CarrierRadGrid_ItemInserted(sender As Object, e As GridInsertedEventArgs)
        Dim msg As String = String.Format("New carrier (Carrier Code: {0}) added to the database.", e.Item.Cells(6).Text)
        Log(msg)
        MessageBox(msg)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function SetCommentsField(e As GridCommandEventArgs) As GridCommandEventArgs
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.Cells(18).Text) Then
            Dim update As String = e.Item.Cells(17).Text
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(update) Then
                e.Item.Cells(18).Text = String.Format("Modified by {0}", update)
            End If
        End If
        Return e
    End Function
```

But when debugging, I find all of the `e.Item.Cells` `Text` properties are "&nbsp;". Yet the record added to the database has the data I put into the fields, as it should.

What could be missing? Or extra?

EDIT: Including the whole RadGrid, instead of only the part I thought was relevant.

Comment: Been a few years since I've dabbled with RadGrid so I could be confused, but from memory there is also a value property you might be better inspecting than the Text.  Would also suggest the type of thing you're doing here might be a better done on the data object you've got your RadGrid bound to

Comment: You should be accessing the edit control most likely and when consuming item command you should cast your item to `gridDataItem` so that from there you can access the edit item control. That is where you new value should live. The &nbsp; is what telerik applies to a data bound cell in place of null/empty. Your change has not been saved to the cell's text value yet. Additionally, your grid markup is important here. Please add it to your OP!

Comment: I work with RadGrid on a daily basis and haven't done much with the auto updates as I usually pass that off to an object to be handled elsewhere. That said, looking back at the documentation, a lot of what you need to do next will be dependent upon your radgrid markup and how it is defined. Additionally, try to avoid getting your columns using indexes. If someone added a column somewhere it could quite literally break all of your code if they don't know to go update each individual index being used. Better to reference the columns by name instead.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless, I have found no way during runtime to determine the index, but I completely agree with the thought. Any clue on how to find it? The closest I have come is CellIndexHierarchical, which is only visible in debugging. I tried using a name as an index for Item, like `Item("CarrierScac")` but it says no such overload exists. Also, in case it will help, I'm including the entire RadGrid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are two options to access the cell data.

1. This accesses the newly inserted data using a hashtable/dictionary. It only retrieves data from EditItems so read-only rows are not included
2. This converts your editItem to a data item and accesses the current cell which you will find is consistently `&nbsp;` because the data has not been put there yet. THe data entered only exists in the edit items.

```
    Protected Sub CarrierRadGrid_InsertCommand(sender As Object, e As GridCommandEventArgs)
        '1
        Dim insertValues As New Hashtable()
        CType(e.Item, GridEditableItem).ExtractValues(insertValues)
        Dim dd = insertValues("CarrierScac")
        
        '2
        Dim item As GridDataItem = CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)
        Dim itemD = item("CarrierScac").Text
        e = SetCommentsField(e)
    End Sub
```

The above should get you what you need I suspect, however to add some color

Telerik uses `&nbsp;` to denote an empty/null cell text field which makes sense here because the cell text you are trying to grab does not exist. It IS empty and you ARE accessing it. The fields you are accessing, however, are read only and there does not appear to be a default value. Are you setting that elsewhere? I've included a function below that checks for `String.IsNullOrEmpty` and `&nbsp;` that we use frequently to spare some logic. I'd put it in a safe place and consume it as needed because empty cells in a radgrid will never actually be `string.empty`.

```vb
    Public Function RadGridCellIsNullOrEmpty(value As String) As Boolean
        value = value.Trim()
        Return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) OrElse value.Contains("&nbsp;"))
    End Function

    Private Shared Function SetCommentsField(byRef e As GridCommandEventArgs) As GridCommandEventArgs

        If RadGridCellIsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.Cells(18).Text) Then
            Dim update As String = e.Item.Cells(17).Text
            If Not RadGridCellIsNullOrEmpty(update) Then
                e.Item.Cells(18).Text = String.Format("Modified by {0}", update)
            End If
        End If
        Return e
    End Function
```

Comment: The fields are stored in the database, of course, though the data I need to access, which this provides, is in the item being inserted or edited, not the data in the database. I have tested, and method 1 works well. The hashtable works, though I can't see where it gets the values from the GridEditableItem; the KeyValues property throws an exception when debugging: ArgumentOutOfRangeException. But the hashtable also gives me the column names to use as indices, which is also very helpful.

Comment: It pulls them from the edit/insert controls. There is a good resource here: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/extracting-values